# Replace "_" with "|" in a file on 5th field only

Tags: text-processing

My file has the content below:

```
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat_123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1_123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2_123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

I need to replace `_` with `|` but only on the 5th field only.

Expected output:

```
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

Answer (score 20):

With `awk`, use [`gsub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) on the 5th field:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub("_",FS,$5)}1' file
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}`
  Set the field separator to `|`. This way, we can address `$5` as the 5th field and so on.
- `{gsub("_",FS,$5)}`
  Replace all the `_` in the 5th field with `FS`. That is, with `|`.
- `1`
  Trigger awk's default action: print the current (modified) record.

Comment: Golf! `gsub("_",FS,$5)+1`.

Answer (score 8):

With `sed` provided the 5th field has only one `_` to be replaced

```
$ sed -E 's/^(([^|]+\|){4}[^_]+)_/\1|/' ip.txt 
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

Solution with `perl` (similar to `awk` one) if all `_` in 5th field are to be replaced:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[4] =~ tr/_/|/; print join "|",@F' ip.txt 
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

Comment: If using Gnu sed, you could have something like `s///5` which would only replace the 5th match.

Comment: @someonewithpc, I don't think that is how it works.. it would replace 5th occurrence anywhere in the line... in this case, even `sed 's/_/|/'` would work, but in real data there may be `_` spread anywhere

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily do that. You could make it so it matches all fields, but only replaces the fifth.

Comment: @someonewithpc explain with this example? `echo 'a_c_f_d_e_f_d|2|3|4|5_6|7' | sed 's/_/|/5'`

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -ne '$F[4]=~s/_/|/; print join "|", @F' file
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

The `-a` makes `perl` act like `awk`, splitting each input line on the character given by `-F` into fields saved in the array `@F`. Then, we substitute `_` with `|` on the 5th field (arrays start at 0, so `$F[4]` is the 5th field) and then print the array joined by `|`.

You could also set the array separator to `|` and print `"@F"` which does the same thing but more concisely:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -ne '$"="|"; $F[4]=~s/_/|/; print "@F"' file
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

Of course, in your specific example, the `_` in the 5th field is also the first on in the line, so if your file is actually like that, it is enough to do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/_/|/' file 
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

Or

```
$ sed 's/_/|/' file 
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

You can use the same approach with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'sub("_","|")' file 
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

Or, to specify only the 5th field and replace all occurrences of `_` in the 5th field, a shorter version of [@fedorqui's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312894/22222):

```
$ awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' 'gsub("_","|",$5)' file 
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat1|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
rat|minty|ruhul|balaji|rat2|123|decode|rat_123|abc|def|ghi|jkl|rat|cde|ind|rat
```

Note that these two `awk` solutions will only print on lines where the substitution was successful. If you can have lines that don't match the pattern (no `_` in the 5th field), use @fedorqui's approach or one of the perl ones instead.

Comment: Interesting! Regarding your awk approaches: using `sub()` will make awk replace just once, so `rat_1_2_3` will become `rat|1_2_3`. OP did not address this edge case, but it is worth noting (and the reason I used `gsub()` instead). Regarding printing the lines that have matched the pattern or not, Kaz [suggested](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312892/replace-with-in-a-file-on-5th-field-only/312894#comment550092_312894) a nice trick: `sub()+1` so that it will always evaluate to True and hence print the line.

Comment: @fedorqui you're quite right about `gsub`, of course, but since you've already mentioned it, I thought I'd go for `sub`. Note that I only used it for the example which assumes that we only want to replace the 1st `_` on the line. And yeah, Kaz's golf is pretty neat!

Comment: `Note that I only used it for the example which assumes that we only want to replace the 1st _ on the line.` probably good to add that in answer... and specify that the last awk solution will replace all occurrences

Comment: @Sundeep OK, I made that explicit in the last example. I already mention that some of the others only remove the 1st `_`: *Of course, in your specific example, the _ in the 5th field is also the first on in the line, so if your file is actually like that, it is enough to do:*